# Flash streaming client

Tags: flash, streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client

I can't find a Flash Streaming Client on the net.
Maybe i use the wrong term in Google, but this seems like an obvious need and i don't want to learn programming with Flash for this simple need. When i use the term rtsp, i only find standalone software.
I simply need a good already programmed client with a nice interface, open-source or proprietary. Something like http://sublimevideo.net/ for Html5, but they don't support rtsp yet.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Flash doesn't support RTSP, instead it uses RTMP. Besides that, I recommend JW Player, http://www.longtailvideo.com/players

Comment: Thanks, JW Player has everything i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lars-blasjo answered the question in the comments, he recommended the [JW PLayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players).